# How to open the data from R to excel?

Tags: r

I have to paste the data to excel, but the data is to large to copy in R.

The code I have tried is the following:

```
r1
library(clipr)
write_clip(r1) # paste r1 in Excel and organize the table in Excel to your desired format
```

Comment: [Write a data frame to a delimited file](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/write_delim.html) is very good for passing data to and from excel.

Answer (score 0):

As for Mac and your login name is sbmvno then,
You may write.csv(DataFram, "/Users/sbmvno/Documents/myfile.csv") and excel can open any csv file.

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I've already tried this solution, before I asked this quesion. But I cannot find this cvs file in my macbook. I don't know how to open it.

Comment: Revised to see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

If it's a dataframe:

```r
write.table(r1, "clipboard", sep = '\t')
```

Sometimes there is a problem with the size of the object, if this is the case you can increase memory size allocated to clipboard by putting a number that is a power of two

```r
write.table(r1, "clipboard-16384", sep = '\t')
```

OR

you could use `view_in_xl` from the `viewxl` package, it opens a temporary excel file with your data.frame in it:

```r
viewxl::view_in_xl(r1)
```